# How do I save every value of k in the loop?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a code that calculates this infinite formula as many times as I want...
3 + 4/(2*3*4) - 4/(4*5*6) + 4/(6*7*8) - 4/(8*9*10) + 4/(10*11*12) - 4/(12*13*14)....

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double a = 2;
    double b = 3;
    double c = 4;

    double g = 2;
    double t = 3;
    double n = 4;
    int A = 0;

    while (A < 10)
    {
        double d = 4 / (a * b * c);
        double e = -4 / (g * t * n);
        double k = d + e;

        if (A % 2 == 0)
        {

            g += 2;
            t += 2;
            n += 2;
            A++;
        }
        else if (A % 2 == 1)
        {
            a += 2;
            b += 2;
            c += 2;
            A++;
            Console.WriteLine(k);
            
            //3.1415926
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Please check [ask] and elaborate on what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I mean how do I store the value of k every time the loop starts?

Comment: write to file, to db etc... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Krispy Like Shaybakov indicates, "save" and "store" can mean many things... what do you mean by "store"? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

To save your values of k to a file, you can use a StreamWriter instead of Console.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("output.txt");

    // ...

    writer.WriteLine(k);
}
```